# background black screen on dropdown open in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello friends i want to show a black opacity screen on bootstrap dropdown open i use this following script for this

```
var modal = document.getElementById('black');

  window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
     }
 }


$('.drp').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

$('.drp').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
 modal.style.display = "block";
```

});

and dropdown code is following

```
<li class="drp dropdown mega-dropdown lst-mbl">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg top-btn dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mega-dropdown-menu up-caret">

<li>
                        <a href="#myProfile" data-toggle="modal">
        <span class="lst-icon"><i class="icon-user icons"></i></span>
        <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">My Profile</span><br><span style="">To help improve accessibility for people using </span></p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="lst-icon"><i class="icon-clock icons"></i></span>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Order History</span><br><span style="">To help improve accessibility for people using </span></p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

but i used following code to stop closing on inside click in dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown a').on('click', function (event) {
$(this).parent().toggleClass("open");

  });
  $('body').on('click', function (e) {
if (!$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').is(e.target) && $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open');
}
 });


 });
```

but my background opacity screen is not showing

Comment: Are you sure the design is correct?  Have you tried just showing the black opacity by default to make sure it looks right and can be seen?

Comment: yes my need is when top nav right side dropdown open a black opacity screen is shown like bootstrap modal window show black opacity screen on open my script work fine but one dropdown have form or when i click on btn my drodown close automatic fot this i use mega-dropdown script but using this script my black opacity screen script not working